# Xamarin.iOS: Bundle nib's are not getting copied to Simulator/Device for Debug/Release

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, nib

I'm Binding to an Objective-C native library with Xamarin Custom Bindings.
I got the whole application working in Visual Studio with the generated DLL.
I also added the bundle (of the library I'm binding to) and marked the images and nib's inside it as "Bundle Resources".

**But when I run the App the nib's don't get copied at all to the Simulator/Device.

I know the app/binding is fine because if I manually copy the nib and images the app works as expected.**

I have already tried configuring several locations for the bundle folder but none of them worked:
 - VSProjectFolder/Resources/miAssetKit.bundle/*
 - VSProjectFolder/Resources/*
 - VSProjectFolder/miAssetKit.bundle/*

(I also edited the csproj file to add the "miAssetKit.bundle" Resource Reference instead of the Resources in this last try.)

This is the error I get when using the "VSProjectFolder/Resources/miAssetKit.bundle/" location

> 2014-08-07 12:01:42.832 KPIBindingiOS[4771:70b] @ monotouch:
>   Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
>   Reason: Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle
>   
>   (not yet loaded)' with name 'miKpiValueViewController'

Looking at the mtbserver.log I have this error:

> [07-Aug-2014 14:40:32] Warning: Fail moving file
>   /Users/Manish/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/KPIBindingiOS/decba649-b058-4744-bbb3-22ca560a321e/output/Debug/iPhoneSimulator/KPIBindingiOS.app/miScatterPlotPopView.nib
>   to bundle dir:
>   /Users/Manish/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/KPIBindingiOS/decba649-b058-4744-bbb3-22ca560a321e/bundle/KPIBindingiOS.app/miScatterPlotPopView.nib
>   [07-Aug-2014 14:40:32] Warning: Exception type:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>   /Users/Manish/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/KPIBindingiOS/decba649-b058-4744-bbb3-22ca560a321e/output/Debug/iPhoneSimulator/KPIBindingiOS.app/miScatterPlotPopView.nib
>   does not exist

Comment: Sorry - I don't have the answer but from an emotional perspective, maybe it would help to know you're not alone.  If I figure it out first, I'll be back.

Comment: @TimothyLeeRussell I still haven't managed to get this working, but I found a workaround.
If you copy your entire project to a Mac, and open it with Xamarin Studio it will work (deploy) just fine.

I'm guessing it's a Visual Studio + Xamarin Issue.

Comment: I have a paid subscription and put in a bug report to Xamarin support.  I'll let you know what I find out.

Comment: I thought you needed .xib files inside your solution? At least, that's what I use. I have .xib (empty views) files from Xcode inside my project's solution, that I use to dynamically create all UI controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the .xib files to the iOS project and setting the build action to "Interface Definition". It just worked for me.